# How to play video stream on web application?

Tags: video, video-streaming, multicast

For exemple, I want to play this video stream : udp://@239.100.0.7:1234  in my web application
Like VLC do it.
I want to use it in an IPTV application.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  At least, not directly.

Your browser only supports HTTP, Web Sockets (which uses HTTP), and WebRTC (which includes media channels as well as data channels).

You will need to proxy that stream, muxing it into a support format, and use a supported protocol.  Node.js and FFmpeg are ideal for this.  If you're streaming to more than a single client, consider using a segment-based protocol such as HLS.